# iOS: I am not sure, but my delegate isnt working out as I planned

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have this delegate that is not working out as planned, I have it setup like so. I want to call the function `NSLog(show);` I am not too sure why this isn't work, but works with my other viewcontroller. I must be missing some small detail.

**AccountViewController.h**

```
@protocol AccountViewControllerDelegate;
@interface AccountViewController : UIViewController{

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AccountViewControllerDelegate> accountViewDelegate;
@end

@protocol AccountViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)showLabel;
@end
```

**AccountViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self showLabel];
}

- (void)showLabel {
    if (self.accountViewDelegate) {
        NSLog(@"showlabel");

        [self.accountViewDelegate showLabel];
    }
}
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
-(void)showLabel {
    NSLog(@"SHOW");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly note that delegate should not have strong reference.

So use

```
@property (unsafe_unretained) id <AccountViewControllerDelegate> accountViewDelegate;
```

Now in `MapViewController.m` or `MapViewController.h` conform to this protocol as

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <AccountViewControllerDelegate>{

}
```

Then in `MapViewController.m` please do

```
AccountViewController *accountVC = [[AccountViewController alloc]init]; // initialize it with whatever be like storyboard or nib
accountVC.accountViewDelegate = self;
```

Your `AccountViewController.h` file should look like this

```
@protocol AccountViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
 - (void)showLabel;
@end

@interface AccountViewController : UIViewController{

}
@property (unsafe_unretained) id <AccountViewControllerDelegate> accountViewDelegate;
@end
```

Comment: It seems my mapviewcontroller doesnt recognize the accountviewcontrollerdelegate when trying to conform to it. I add the import and everything. But still doesnt recognize it. "Cannot find protocol delecleration for Accountviewcontroller.

Comment: Please don't make protocol declaration as forward declaration. rather delete the line `@protocol AccountViewControllerDelegate;` & replace it with the code `@protocol AccountViewControllerDelegate <NSObject> .... @end` in `AccountViewController.h` file.

Comment: Also synthesize the `accountViewDelegate` in `AccountViewController.m` file.

Comment: Ok, now it crashes with this message. self=(AccountViewController *const)nil

Answer (score 3):

you haven't shown where you assign the MapViewController to be the delegate of the AccountViewController. Perhaps thats what you are missing

```
//(from somewhere in the MapViewController)

AccountViewController *accountVC = //however you instantiate it (segue, storyboard etc
accountVC.accountViewDelegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what you should have in your different files:

**AccountViewController.h**

Note that "assign" is mainly for primitives like NSInteger, CGFloat, BOOL (that is, for properties that are not objects).  Use "weak" to keep a pointer toward your delegate without incrementing his retain count.

```
@protocol AccountViewControllerDelegate;

@interface AccountViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AccountViewControllerDelegate> accountViewDelegate;
@end

@protocol AccountViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)showLabel;
@end
```

**AccountViewController.m**

Here, it is usually good practice to check if the delegate isn't `nil` and if it has the method you want to call implemented.  Use `respondToSelector` for that.

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self showLabel];
}

- (void)showLabel {
    if (self.accountViewDelegate && [self.accountViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showLabel)]) {
        NSLog(@"showlabel");

        [self.accountViewDelegate showLabel];
    }
}
```

**MapViewController.h**

Be sure to import `"AccountViewController.h"` here.

```
#import "AccountViewController.h"
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <AccountViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

Put the following where you were instantiating your AccountViewController object:

```
//Somewhere
AccountViewController *accountViewController = [[AccountViewController alloc] init];
accountViewController.accountViewDelegate = self;
```

and this is your delegate's method implementation:

```
- (void)showLabel {
    NSLog(@"SHOW");
}
```